# Compare IR operand with a constant in LLVM

Tags: llvm

I have an IR which looks like this:

```
%5=icmp eq i32 %4,0
```

I want to check if the second operand of icmp instruction is 0 or something else. I made use of `getOperand(1)`, which returns the result in `Value *` format. How can I compare it with the constant 0?

Comment: Specifically for 0 it is `val->isZero()`, a bit more tricky for the other constants. I'd recommend to use `match`, see InstructionSimplify.cpp for a lot of examples.

Comment: @SK-logic: `Value` on its own doesn't have `isZero`, that's a method of `ConstantInt`. See my answer for more details

Comment: @EliBendersky, of course, providing a dynamic cast to ConstantInt was successful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a sample pass you can run to find this out:

```
class DetectZeroValuePass : public FunctionPass {
public:
    static char ID;

    DetectZeroValuePass()
        : FunctionPass(ID)
    {}

    virtual bool runOnFunction(Function &F) {
        for (Function::iterator bb = F.begin(), bb_e = F.end(); bb != bb_e; ++bb) {
            for (BasicBlock::iterator ii = bb->begin(), ii_e = bb->end(); ii != ii_e; ++ii) {
                if (CmpInst *cmpInst = dyn_cast<CmpInst>(&*ii)) {
                    handle_cmp(cmpInst);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    void handle_cmp(CmpInst *cmpInst) {
        // Detect cmp instructions with the second operand being 0
        if (cmpInst->getNumOperands() >= 2) {
            Value *secondOperand = cmpInst->getOperand(1);
            if (ConstantInt *CI = dyn_cast<ConstantInt>(secondOperand))
                if (CI->isZero()) {
                    errs() << "In the following instruction, second operand is 0\n";
                    cmpInst->dump();
                }
        }
    }
};
```